# Magento 2 - Rest API - How to get the text of a custom attribute that is a drop-down menu

Tags: rest-api, custom-attributes, text

I have a custom attribute that is a drop-down with the brands of my products.

If I query

```
$query = 'https://example.com/rest/V1/products?'.
"fields=items[id,sku,name,custom_attributes[Brand]]".
'&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1';
```

I get

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 577,
            "sku": "TAC_520UT",
            "name": "Tacometro 520mm Ultra Tunne",
            "custom_attributes": {
                "1": {
                    "attribute_code": "Brand",
                    "value": "415"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The brand is giving me  415, while at the interface that is not a number, is the text "Kamoha"

How can I query for the text of Brand 415 and get "Kamoha" as a Rest API call?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the request you have a product Id, so you simply load the product with product id and use function `getAttributeText` to get product brand value

**Sample Code:**

```
<?php

namespace Mageprince\Test\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class MyClass
{

    private $orderRepository;
   
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getAttributeValue()
    {
        $productId = 577;
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($productId);
        
        echo $product->getAttributeText('Brand'); //Brand is attribute code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but as you can see I am asking to do this from the Rest API and not calling the Magento classes directly in a PHP script. Is not useful for me in this way. If you can translate this into a Rest API query like the one I have posted it may help.